# Set django url pattern in django project not in django app

Tags: python, django

I have a django project `mysite`
and a djano app in a directory (`proto`) called `http`

and here is me url setting:

**mysite/mysite/urls.py**:

```
import proto
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^data/',proto.http.views.DataList.as_view(),name='data')
)
```

**mysite/proto/http/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from proto.http import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^data/$',views.DataList.as_view(),name='data-list'),
)
```

So I can visit : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/`

When I reviewmy code ,I feel weird why I have to set the url twice?

But if I comment out the url pattern in `mysite/proto/http/urls.py`

```
#urlpatterns = patterns('',
#    url(r'^data/$',views.DataList.as_view(),name='data-list'),
#)
```

I got `500` error

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /data/
The included urlconf '<module 'proto.http.urls' from '/Users/Winsome/mysite/proto/http/urls.pyc'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

What is the correct way to set url pattern ??

Comment: Can you *show* what you mean by "hide the url"? Do you comment out that particular line, or do you comment out the three lines with `urlpatterns`, or comments out the complete file?

Comment: I comment out the 3 line

Comment: You might run into a problem with statle `*.pyc` files; just remove them. Alternatively, since you're importing views, make sure you don't import `proto.http.urls` in views.py (or in a module imported by views.py). Such a thing would explain the circular import warning.

Comment: I remove pyc files,and met ````'module' object has no attribute 'views'```` when visit ````http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/````

Comment: You're not fully import `proto.http` in your main urls.py, only `proto`. Yet in the url pattern, you access `proto.http.views`. That normally doesn't work.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current situation with the actual question.